# classification of Riemann surfaces for higher genus?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

It is well known that by uniformization theorem the simply connected Riemann surface can be classified into three equivalent classes by conformal mapping: $C, C^\infty$, and $D$. This may be seen as a generalization of the Riemann mapping theorem. And also as a general fact, the annuli in
$C$ can be classified into equivalent classes of one parameter (they are all conformally equivalent to the unit disk removing a hole of radius $s$). So I'm wondering if there are any similar theorems for Riemann surfaces of the higher genus that generalizes the latter result.

Comment: Search for Teichmuller theory. There's some entries on this site, and some external sites as well. And some good books.

Comment: This is an endless subject. There is a $1$-parameter family of genus $1$ surfaces (the moduli space is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ via the $j$-invariant, and you can compactify to $\mathbb C^\infty$ where the point at infinity parametrizes the unique-up-to-isomorphism nodal genus $1$ curve). For $g \ge 2$, there is a quasiprojective variety of $M_g$ (complex) dimension $3g-3$ (as alluded to in Lee's comment, $M_g$ can be expressed as the quotient of Teichmuller space $\mathcal T_g$, which is diffeomorphic to a ball, by the action of the mapping class group)...

Comment: ...there is also a projective compactification $\overline{M}_g$ due to Deligne-Mumford which "fills in" the boundary with stable curves (unions of Riemann surface which meet at nodes and have finite automorphism group), although this is primarily studied from the perspective of algebraic geometry.